# Is it possible to get python bytecode without using co_code?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, bytecode

Say I am in the python interpreter and define a function as follows:

```
def h(a):
  return a
```

If I want to look at the bytecode (not a disassembly using dis), I can typically use `h.func_code.co_code`. Is there any other way to look at the bytecode?

For example, in the interpreter, if I just type `h` without making it a function call, I get the address of the function. Can I use that address to get the bytecode? Is there some other way?

Some additional info from the comments:

The app is written in python and packed using something like Py2App, cx_freeze, or py2exe. I played some tricks on the executable and now, when launched, the executable dumps me to a python command line. From there, I manually typed my function `h` into the interepeter.

Other attributes of `h.func_code` are present such as `co_varnames`, `co_argcount`, etc, but `co_code` is not.

If I type in `h.func_code.co_code` into the interpreter, I get `'code' object has no attribute 'co_code'`.

**UPDATE**: From the comments again. As far as I can tell the opcodes have been remapped for the python interpreter that was shipped with the app.

Comment: Why isn't `h.func_code.co_code` good enough? Using the memory address is not going to be any easier.

Comment: Because for some reason it isn't there. I'm learning about python reverse engineering and it seems there were some protections added to the piece of software. One of which seems to have made co_code unavailable.

Comment: I very much doubt that. Use `dir()` to find attributes on your objects and explore, using the [python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) as your guide. For example, if `h` is a *method* then you need to get to the wrapped function with `h.im_func` first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, believe me, I have. `dir(h)` shows `func_code`. `dir(h.func_code)` shows the other standard attributes (`co_varnames`, `co_argcount`, etc), but not `co_code`. The piece of software was packaged with Py2App, so it is bundled with its own interpreter. Perhaps some tricks are being played there.

Comment: For starters, do you know it's written in Python? What's it's `type`? (Also, [`dir` can be overriden by the object](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir), don't bet your farm on its output.)

Comment: And what does `type(h)` give you? It could be an extension class (coded in C) for example. Also, what's the `h.func_code.__class__`?

Comment: @delnan, yes, definitely written in Python. The app came with a library.zip file which contains a bunch of pyc files. Furthermore, I've played some tricks which caused the application to dump me to a python interpreter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, `type(h)` returns `function`. I manually entered the function `h` into the interpreter.

Comment: @mikeazo I meant `h` specifically, not the app in general. But apparently it is, judging from your other comments.

Comment: What is the interpreter version? (`import sys; print(sys.version)`)

Comment: @mikeazo that doesn't look like a version string. What's the *full version string*?

Comment: @ecatmur, 2.5.4 (r254:67916, May 13 2011, 16:23:00) [GCC 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)]

Comment: It *is* theoretically possible to remove the `co_code` attribute from the python interpreter. That would require a custom interpreter build. You could still just load all the python code into your own interpreter (just unzip the zipfiles in the `Contents/Resources/` directory and put those on your path.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as far as I can tell, the opcodes were remapped in the custom interpreter. So I would probably have to figure out the mapping, change it in the python interpreter source, then compile my own interpreter.

Comment: @mikeazo: they really, really, really didn't want you to read the bytecode, did they?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeah. But hey, it has been a good learning exercise.

Comment: For future reference, I posted this question on the new [ReverseEngineering.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/is-it-possible-to-get-python-bytecode-without-using-co-code) (couldn't migrate as it was too old).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have defined your own `def h(): pass` dummy function, and that function does not have a `.func_code.co_code` value, then most likely the included python interpreter is a custom compiled version where the `co_code` slot has been cleared.

The work-around is simple, copy the `Contents/Resources` zipfiles (in all subdirs) elsewhere, add those to your `PYTHONPATH` and import the code into your own interpreter.